# How to replace canless recessed led lights with retrofit recessed led lights

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting

These are the [canless recessed led lights](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NPTQ2JQ) I have in my ceiling now.

These are the new [retrofit recessed lights](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C28C3H2P) that I'd like to install instead.

Considerations: The new retrofit lights have metal clips that slide into brackets on the inside of cans, but my old lights are canless so there is nowhere for the new lights to attach to.

How do I replace these lights?  I'm open any and all suggestions.  Any help or direction or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't have cans, why do you want to install lights where the primary feature is that they are preconfigured to install on cans?  If you just like the appearance you should keep shopping.

Comment: I'm not going to make this an answer but the answer is to buy some can lights, install them, throw away the lights, and then retrofit these ones.  Can probably find some discarded can lights in a dumpster outside any renovation.

Comment: Your question is basically how do I use something for an unintended purpose.   You can fit square pegs in round holes with modification...but it is much easier and wiser to just get round pegs.